Can't use OpportunityLineItem.EffectiveDate__c on Before Insert Update flow
I have to check in an OpportunityLineItem Before Insert Update flow that there aren't other OLI of the same product with matching dates. My issue is that I can't use EffectiveDate__c as it is a formula field that retrieves information from QuoteLineItem, which I can't access (EffectiveDate__c = QuoteLineItem.EffectiveDate__c).
How can I bypass this issue?
Thanks for your help.

I'm confused -- the question title discusses OpportunityLineItem but the formula field is based on QuoteLineItem.  There's no schema relationship between OpportunityLineItem and QuoteLineItem. Please use [edit] to clarify

OpportunityLineItem has a standard QuoteLineItemId, but it isn't accesible. I finally was able to reach the information I needed.

see OpportunityLineItem Object Ref -- no such field in schema.  Regardless, as a service to the community, you should post your answer

I used a Get Records to retrieve QuoteLineItems and match by the OportunityLineItem that triggered the flow.

When you say "I finally was able to reach the information I needed", does this mean you resolved your issue?  If so, you can post an answer for your own question.  If it is not resolved, please [edit] your post to clarify and include more details.
